# Python: Adaptive xticks for matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, xticks

Good evening

For a coding exercise I am generating a plot with matplotlib. Let f be a real-valued function (which is unimportant for my question). I'm now having trouble with my xticks spacing, as n (amount of data) gets large. Do you know how to make this adaptive to a certain degree?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n = # positive integer, specified by user in console

x = [m for m in range(1,n+1)]
y = [f(i) for i in x]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.title("Berechnungszeitdiagramm für die Funktion")
plt.xlim(1,n)
plt.xticks([i for i in range(1,n+1)])
plt.xlabel("n")
plt.ylim(0,np.max(vector)+1)
plt.ylabel("Berechnungszeit (in ns)")
plt.grid()
```

To illustrate my problem, consider the x-axes of the following generated plots:

[Plot for n=15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQiok.png)

[Plot for n=100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9d6S.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just edit you list comprehension in `plt.xticks` as follows:

```py
plt.xticks([i for i in range(1, n+1, stepsize)])
```

where `stepsize` is an integer. If you always want 15 ticks you could set `stepsize = n // 15` for example

Comment: Is there a way of extracting your stepsize parameter from the given length of the data list? I'd like to not specify this manually but have the spacing be calculated as a function of the length of my x.

Comment: I've added it to my answer. You can also replace n with ```len(x)``` if n not always is the length of x

Comment: Thank you! This is nice. :D

Comment: You're welcome. If this answers your question, just mark the answer as a solution, so anyone who has a similar question can profit.